# Enable MD5 or SHA1 hash functions in IIS

Tags: windows, ftp, iis, hashing, checksum

I have an IIS FTP server on my Windows 10. I am using a third party library [FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP) to download a file.

This library has a function to compare two files. And I am trying to compare my downloaded file and the file on the server. But I am getting an error checksum not supported.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234622/when-executing-comparefileasync-outputs-checksumnotsupported-fluentftp
According to this answer, my server does not support any hash algorithms. Can I get a guide on how to enable MD5 or SHA1 or any other good algorithm in the above link in my IIS server? So that I can compare files with my FTP server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IIS server does not support any checksum calculation.

There's no way to enable it.

---

*Your related question about FileZilla server: [Enable checksum on FileZilla server](https://superuser.com/q/1619475/213663)*