# Enable checksum on FileZilla server

Tags: ftp, hashing, checksum

How can I enable checksum on the FileZilla server? I want to compare files after downloading on my Android device via [FluentFTP library](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP).

The following checksum FTP commands are supported by this library: `MD5`, `XMD5`, `XCRC`, `XSHA1`, `XSHA256`, `XSHA512`.

Comment: Your related question about IIS: [Enable MD5 or SHA1 hash functions in IIS](https://superuser.com/q/1619294/213663)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the FileZilla Server installation folder locate file `FileZilla Server.xml`. That's typically:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\FileZilla Server\FileZilla Server.xml
```

In the file, locate the `<Settings>` tag and within it find `Enable HASH` item and set it to `1`:

```xml
    <Settings>
        ...
        <Item name="Enable HASH" type="numeric">1</Item>
        ...
    </Settings>
```

Restart the server.

Note that this enables a support for `HASH` command. While it's not in the list in your question, FluentFTP supports it too.

The FileZilla FTP server supports SHA-1, SHA-512 and MD5 hash algorithms with the `HASH` command.

```
ftp> open example.com
Connected example.com.
220-EXPERIMENTAL BUILD
220-NOT FOR PRODUCTION USE
220-
220 Implementing draft-bryan-ftp-hash-06
202 UTF8 mode is always enabled. No need to send this command.
User (example.com:(none)): username
331 Password required username
Password:
230 Logged on
ftp> quote FEAT
211-Features:
 MDTM
 REST STREAM
 SIZE
 MLST type*;size*;modify*;
 MLSD
 AUTH SSL
 AUTH TLS
 PROT
 PBSZ
 UTF8
 CLNT
 MFMT
 HASH SHA-1*;SHA-512;MD5
 EPSV
 EPRT
211 End
ftp> quote OPTS HASH SHA-512
200 Hash algorithm set to SHA-512
ftp> quote HASH filename
213 SHA-512 8c5341c24561f880d5222747adbbb9c9...
ftp>
```

All the `EXPERIMENTAL BUILD ... Implementing draft-bryan-ftp-hash-06` header is an indication that the `HASH` command is enabled. Also note the `HASH SHA-1*;SHA-512;MD5` in the `FEAT` command response.

Comment: This does not work anymore in (not-yet-stable) FileZilla Server 1.0.0 – yet?